# It is possible to dock a laptop to a desktop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, docking-station, docking

I would like to dock my laptop to my desktop so that I can work from both systems. I think I have seen this done before but, the only docks I can find online are docks that add more USB ports and allow the laptop to connect to multiple monitors. The idea is, I come in, plug the laptop to the dock. I am working on my desktop and then quickly switch to the laptop and then back. All using the same peripherals (two monitors, mouse, keyboard)

Any ideas, suggestions, or direct answers are welcome as this is something I am not at all familiar with.

Comment: To my knowledge this sort of consumer product does not exist, what you can do is if your docking your laptop into the same network you can VNC the laptop and achieve similar results

Comment: Approximations that come to mind, KVM and Synergy / Mouse without Borders

Comment: @AthomSfere, Thanks for that. I haven't tried the Mouse without Borders but, after reading up on it that may be what I go with. KVM just leads to more hardware which I would like to avoid if possible.